# Prevent state from updating when i update the same in vue component after dispatching

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I am new in this world of Vue and Vuex, I am creating a list of customers having multiple products. to achieve this I've created a customer array in Vue component in which I have products array where I push product items to add multiple products. On saving customer, I simply dispatch it to Vuex store and push it to customer array in my state. My Problem is when I add product item in the second customer, vuejs adds product items in all customers.

Vue Component

```
 data() {
    return {
      customer: {
        cus_name: ""
        cus_product: [
          {
            product_name: "",
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addProduct() {
      this.customer.cus_product.push({
        product_name: ""
      });
    },

    removeProduct(index) {
      this.customer.cus_product.splice(index, 1);
    },

    addCustomer() {
      this.$store.dispatch("addCustomer", this.customer);
    }
  }
};
```

vuex Store

```
const state = {
    customers: []
};


const mutations = {
    addCustomer(state, customerData) {
        state.customers.push(customerData);
    }
};

const actions = {
    addCustomer(vuexContext, customerData) {
        vuexContext.commit('addCustomer', customerData);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a product in `addProduct()`, your code does not say to whom the product should be added. I mean you set `cus_name: ""` and this never has been updated when you add the product.

I do not know how your whole application looks like, but one thing is sure: we need to tell define the customer to whom the products must be added:

```
addProduct() {
  // I add the product to the customer begueradj, for instance
  this.customer.cus_name = "begueradj"
  this.customer.cus_product.push({
    product_name: ""
  });
},
```

That was in your Vue component.

Now in your store's mutation and  you have first to look for the customer which name is "begueradj", then we wil lface 2 cases here:

1. If the customer exists already, then update only his products list
2. If the customer is new, then add him to the customers list

In plain Kabyle language, this would lead us to this simple code:

```
const mutations = {
  addCustomer(state, customerData) {
     // We check first if there is a customer whose name is the one we want to add products to:
     const customer = state.customer.find(customer => customer.cus_name === customerData.cus_name)
     if (customer) {
       // If we found him, then update his products list:  
       customer.cus_product.concat(customerData.cust_product)
     } else {
       // Customer does not exist, then add him to the customers list
       state.customer.push(customerData)
     }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with Vue or Vuex. It is because of the fact that Javascript assign arrays and Objects (non primitive types) by reference not by value. It passes the exact object or array not a copy of it, so any change that happens on the original affects the new one.

You can try this:

```
const mutations = {
    addCustomer(state, customerData) {
        const customerDataCopy = Object.assign({}, customerData);
        customerDataCopy.cus_product = [].concat(customerData.cus_product);
        state.customers.push(customerDataCopy);
    }
};
```

Or you can use a module that creates a deep copy of non primitive types like `deep-copy` npm package (0 deps package) to avoid this kind of problems.

```
const dcopy = require('deep-copy');
const mutations = {
    addCustomer(state, customerData) {
        const customerDataCopy = dcopy(customerData);
        state.customers.push(customerDataCopy);
    }
};
```